# Global database of study programmes?

Tags: masters, bachelor, databases

I'm interested in finding all undergraduate/graduate study programmes on the topic of "Sustainable Consumption".

Is there a global database across all universities and teaching institutions that allows the user to search for study programmes filtered by a certain topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *global* database that I know of. To illustrate: our Masters' courses do not, to the best of my knowledge, submit details to any. And we run several that relate to sustainable consumption, for some meaning of that phrase. I won't link to them, because that's just going to look spammy, but if you're interested, a quick web search will find them for you:

- MSc in Economics and Policy of Energy and the Environment
- MRes Energy Demand Studies
- Masters in Sustainable Resources (SRES)

Although there's no *global* database, there are national ones. For example, there is a site for Postgrad courses in the UK: [here's their list of 1521 courses in the UK that have "sustainable" in the title or short description](http://www.prospects.ac.uk/search_courses_results.htm?criteria.keyword=sustainable). But note that of the three I listed, only two are present in that list, so that particular search is not comprehensive: a course might be about sustainable consumption, without including the word "sustainable" in the title or short description.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you will find a global database, but for graduate studies and beyond, the [Euraxess portal](http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/) is pan-European and all EU-funded positions must be advertised through it. Unfortunately, "Sustainable Consumption" does not return any hits on the job search, but perhaps other keywords will be more successful.

Comment: "all EU-funded positions must be advertised through it" - I can imagine this might be less useful than it sounds. For instance, I suspect it will contain positions that have become vacant and are open only for the remainder of a running project, and whoever gets employed on them is supposed to somehow finish the remaining few tasks in the project before switching to something quite different when the actual funding planned for that new employee kicks in.